# How to have a progress label repainted while working on a locked bitmap?

Tags: c#

I am modifying a large bitmap using BitmapData, LockBits, unsafe and byte*. Absolutely no problem about that.
I would like to display the operation progress in a Label control but, quite obviously, it is not repainted.
If I add Application.DoEvents() to force repainting I get the error "Bitmap region is already locked".
Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: Do the bitmap manipulation on a background worker thread, then the GUI thread will remain responsive.

Comment: So, if I update the Label text in that background thread, it will be repainted?

Comment: to be precise, if you update the label text *from the background thread using invoke*, it will be repainted. [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661561/1132334). If you included relevant code in your post, it will be easier to diagnose and fix that reentrance bug "...is already locked".